# List iterators incompatible

Tags: c++, list, iterator

When I run my program step by step through the debugger I do not get this error. However when I actually run the program I get it every time. It breaks at this loop:

```
auto ships = sprites.begin();
auto misscnt = sprites.begin(); misscnt++; misscnt++; //missiles start at the 3rd item on list every time.

while (misscnt != sprites.end())        //Missile Collision
    {
        ships = sprites.begin();
        ships++;
        if (dynamic_cast<Missile*>(*misscnt)->Collides((*ships)->GetLeft(), (*ships)->GetTop(), (*ships)->GetWidth(), (*ships)->GetHeight()) && dynamic_cast<Missile*>(*misscnt)->GetID() == "PlayerMiss")
        {
            ships--;

            (*ships)->AddToScore(10);
            sys->playSound(FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, eHit, false, 0);
            while (true)
            {
                ships = sprites.begin();
                ships++;
                int x, y;
                x = rand() % Console::WindowWidth;
                y = rand() & Console::WindowHeight;
                if ((*ships)->GoodSpot(x, y, *(*--ships)))
                {
                    ships++;
                    (*ships)->SetLeft(x);
                    (*ships)->SetTop(y);
                    break;
                }
            }
            delete (*misscnt);
            sprites.erase(misscnt);
            ships = sprites.begin();
        }

        else if (dynamic_cast<Missile*>((*misscnt))->Collides((*ships)->GetLeft(), (*ships)->GetTop(), (*ships)->GetWidth(), (*ships)->GetHeight()) && dynamic_cast<Missile*>((*misscnt))->GetID() == "EnemyMiss")
        {
            (*ships)->SetLives((*ships)->GetLives() - 1);
            if ((*ships)->GetLives() > 1)
                sys->playSound(FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, pHit, false, 0);
            if ((*ships)->GetLives() == 1)
                sys->playSound(FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, LastLife, false, 0);
            if ((*ships)->GetLives() == 0)
            {
                bgmusic->setPaused(true);
                sys->playSound(FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, pDie, false, 0);
                Sleep(4000);
                play = false;
                break;
                }
            while (true)
            {
                int x, y;
                x = rand() % Console::WindowWidth;
                y = rand() & Console::WindowHeight;
                if ((*ships)->GoodSpot(x, y, *(*++ships)))
                {
                    ships--;
                    (*ships)->SetLeft(x);
                    (*ships)->SetTop(y);
                    break;
                }
            }
            delete (*misscnt);
            sprites.erase(misscnt);
            ships = sprites.begin();
        }
        else
            misscnt++;
    }
```

The program never goes into either the if or the else if bodies so whenever a missile is fired it is added to the list. In the loop, if the missile doesn't collide when anything it should increment misscnt and check the next missile (if there is one).

EDIT: The error says

list iterators incompatible
File:: F:\VS2013\VC\include\list
Line: 289

I think the line is talking about the file "list".

When it breaks VS points to the while loop condition saying that it is the next line to execute.

Comment: What is the exact error and what line is it on?

Comment: The old "erasing iterator while looping with iterator" dilemma. It would be easier if you just used std::partition and partition the dead ships, and then delete/erase them outside of that loop.  It would also help if you didn't dynamic_cast and instead used proper OO techniques such as virtual functions.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie We haven't been taught partition at all so I can't use it. Also, the ships don't die. Just the missiles. Would the dynamic_cast really cause the issue that I am seeing though?

Comment: @graham.reeds Added error info now, sorry.

Comment: @user3334986 - You just have too much going on in that loop that would cause such an issue. My suggestion is not to erase anything and mark it as "dead". Then outside the loop, you go through the dead targets and erase them. That is the easiest solution. In essence that is what std::partition would have done (move the dead ships to the end of the container which you can then process separately). Erasing elements while iterating over them is one of the things that causes these issues. My advice is to avoid doing that whenever possible.

Comment: You also didn't post exactly what those containers you're using are.  Are they vectors, std::list, etc.?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The missiles do have a bool for active. And I do have the code set up already to delete those missiles. So I changed the deleting in this loop to setting them to non active, but now I get the same error in that loop. Not sure how to post that code here, as a separate answer?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie They are std::list

Comment: Well, if you go and erase iterators while looping, and the erasure of the iterator causes the container to invalidate all of its iterators, then your loop is flawed.  You should remove those lines that removes a ship entirely from the loop and instead replace them with the active flag being false.  First try that.  Then outside of that loop delete the ones that have the active flag as false.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That is what I am doing now, but I get the same error now in the loop that deletes the inactive missiles.

Comment: `y = rand() & Console::WindowHeight;` This is most likely a typo and needs to be `%` instead of `&`

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot going on in that while() loop.  It should be refactored so that it doesn't get these issues with invalid iterator.  The code below has not been compiled, but it will be used to try to illustrate my point:

```
#include <algorithm>

bool IsAlive(ships& s)
{ return s.IsActive(); }

void DeleteMe(ship& s)
{  delete &s; }

//...
auto ships = sprites.begin();
auto misscnt = sprites.begin(); 
std::advance(misscnt, 2);

while (misscnt != sprites.end())        //Missile Collision
{
    // do the collision handling
    bool hasCollided = DoCollisionHandling( misscnt ); 
    if ( hasCollided )
       misscnt->setActive(false);
    ++misscnt;
}

// remove the inactive ones
list<sprites>::iterator pt = std::partition(sprites.begin(), sprites.end(), IsAlive); 
std::for_each(pt, sprites.end(), DeleteMe);
std::erase(pt, sprites.end());
```

Given what you posted, the code above should be a synopsis of what you're trying to achieve.  Note that the only thing that is done is to call DoCollisionHandling (which should be a virtual function, overriden for each type), and it returning whether a collision occurred or not.  The DoCollisionHandling( ) should *not* be erasing items.

Then outside of the while loop, we partition the dead ones to the right of the partition, so that we can delete them (or do whatever we want to do with them later).  The "pt" is the iterator that is the dividing line between the ones that are alive and the ones that are dead.

There are probably better ways to do this, but one way I don't recommend is trying to be too cute in loops like this where you're deleting items being iterated over.  Unless it is a toy or simple loop, doing things like that always seems to cause trouble.  Better to just mark the items, and process them later on.